# Cocoa Touch Framework: Can't detect custom class in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, collectionview

I have Cocoa Touch Framework with custom UICollectionView class. And right now I want to implement it in my project. However, it can't detect my custom UICollectionView class that I made in my cocoa touch framework.
NB: Custom class in image below is manually typed (not auto complete like it used to)
[image]

[image]

Here's my Cocoa Framework Class:

```
public class LATransitionCell: UICollectionViewCell, LATransition {
    private var initFrame: CGRect?
    private var initCornerRadius: CGFloat?

    override public func awakeFromNib() {
    }
}
```

Here's my View Controller class that I want to import that class (and in this viewcontroller class, the LATransitionCell is performing well)

```
import LACoreUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    private var hiddenCells: [LATransitionCell] = []
    private var expandedCell: LATransitionCell?
    private var isStatusBarHidden = false

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Is that any idea why this happen and how to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this by typed framework's name in the module under custom class. Then clean build folder, then re-build the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to define it on the wrong element, try selecting the cell element and then try to associate the `UICollectionViewCell`:

[image]

Comment: I did the same thing in the cell but still same.